# Change directory last opened date every time you `cd` in Terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, smart-folders

I use a `Recent` Smart folder, that depends on last opened date of the folder. It works fine when you browsing the Finder, but it doesn't register change when I use `cd` command in a Terminal.

Is there a way to change last opened date of the folder every time I `cd` to it in a terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Open .bash_profile - or create it if it doesn't exist.

Add the line:

```
tcd () { touch "$1" && cd "$1"; }
```

and save the file.

Source your modified .bash_profile with `source ~/.bash_profile` or close all Terminal windows currently open.

Use `tcd folder_name` to cd to it **and** modify the access date.

---

You can refine this by adding a condition that the argument has to be a folder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't want to use another command other than `cd`. Also it seems that the script would modify the "Edited" date, not the "Last opened" date.

Comment: @Boykodev touch changes the modification and access date!

Comment: yeah, you're right.

Comment: `touch` and `cd` - interesting...